# edit content of table and send changes to database

Tags: python, html, django

I have a table that made it editable!something like this.

```
<table>
      <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Code</th>
      </tr>
      {% for item in list %}
      <tr>
      <td contenteditable='true'>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td contenteditable='true'>{{item.code}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
</table>
```

also I have a 'submit' button end of the table to submit users changes. 
now my questions are how to send edited data to my server?
how to find which content was edited? which item of the list and which attribute of that was edited?
also is there any better idea to editable table?

I use django2 on my backend side.

Comment: you can use an ajax request .